# Spring boot mongoDB autowired null repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, autowired

I am experimenting with spring and MongoDB.
In my project I have a repository and a service which has a scheduled method.
The problem is, that the repository doesn't get autowired, it is always null.

- Autowire works correctly in the main application class (tested it by implementing CommandLineRunner )
- The service is found by componentScan (the constructor is called)

Am I missing somethig?

**directory**

[image]

**MachineApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MachineApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MachineApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Worker.java**

```
@Service
public class Worker {

    @Autowired
    private LineDataRepository lineDataRepository;
    @Autowired
    private LineRepository lineRepository;
    ...
    public Worker() {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(lineDataRepository);//null
        System.out.println(lineRepository);//null
    }
}
```

**LineDataRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface LineDataRepository extends MongoRepository<LineData, String> {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@EnableMongoRepositories` to the MachineApplication to let it detect Mongo repositories.

See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't create `mongoDbFactory` and `mongoTemplate` bean, without this bean no connection will be made to your mongoDB. Below is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("admin", "password");
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "myspring", userCredentials);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```